# New iTunes Connect In-App Purchase submission?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, app-store-connect

So with the new iTunes Connect that came with iOS 8 I have my apps and one of them needs three of my in app purchases need to be submitted for review along with my binary. And in the old iTunes Connect that was very easy but in the new one I can't figure out how to do it!

So my question is this:

In the new iTunes Connect, how do I submit an in app purchase for review ALONG WITH THE BINARY JUST LIKE THE FIRST IN APP PURCHASE FOR THAT APP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue but I overcame it by adding the screenshot of the in-app. Make sure that the in-app product is in the "**Ready to Submit**" state. Once the in-app is in the "**Ready to Submit**" state, it appears  the section to select the in-apps. Check my screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Okay! Well mine is developer action needed. Since I had nonconsumables and added consumables. Since I was changing my revenue model, they wanted me to submit it with the binary. How can I get developer action needed to ready to submit?

Comment: Okay I figured it out. For anyone else with this issue, what you half to do is go into your language in the in app purchase (where you set name and description) and change something. I just put an extra space in the description. This will change the in app purchase to waiting for review and then when that is true and all in app purchases are waiting for review, submit your app born art and the two will still be correlated. This worked for me!